# Manually add Browser History Entry (Cross Browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if it's possible in any way to achieve, what I want to do.
I got single page website with some sections. Something like this:

```
<div class="page pageOne"></div>

<div class="page pageTwo"></div>

<div class="page pageThree"></div>

<div class="page pageFour"></div>
```

When you open up the site, pages 2, 3 and 4 got `display:none` and the first one `display:block`. When I click a link in my navigation, the current "page" fades out and whatever link you've clicked on, the belonging section fades in. The links look like this:

```
<a class="pageChange" href=".pageFour">Four</a>
```

And here's the jQuery code:

```
$(".pageChange").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".page").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(href).fadeIn();
    }, 200);
});
```

What's pretty obvious is when I click the browsers *back button*, it won't fade the previous section in. It will just return to the previous site I've opened.
So my question is: Is there a way to add a history entry in the browser, when clicking on a link? So I can press the back button and it fades the previous section in?
To get the visible section before clicking a link, I've done this:

```
var currentPage = $(".page:visible").attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

But unfortunately that's no use to what I want to achieve.
I'd be incredibly happy if someone could provide me some help of how I could approach this (or if it's even possible)

Comment: It's certainly possible, using pushState: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your quick response. So you _have_ to change the URL to get this to work (that wouldn't be a problem ofc)?

Comment: Yep, the URL has to be changed. Although you can just add a fragment so you don't redirect or unload the current page, eg `foo.html#bar`

Comment: @AnoopGarlapati I don't see in any way how that would be considered a duplicate...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the browser [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to update the URL. Then you can detect the back and forth movement with [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) and call your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the super similar situation! The best solution my friend would be to use https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ You can read the code how he's doing on github. Basically you have to record the scrolling and later handle using a function for back and forth browsing.

Comment: I know that fullPage plugin, but never realized you could use the back button to get to the previous section! Thanks!

Comment: I would highly recommend you to use that @TobiasGlaus also doing on your own could lead you to a lot of bugs or will consumed time.